# create/modify file content permission without delete/rename permission?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Is it possible to allow users to:

- create a txt file
- modify the content of the txt file

but disallow:

- rename/delete this txt file?

Comment: If forget about Rename, can i still set the permission to allow Edit the content but disallow Delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can take away permissions to Delete, but I'm not sure about renaming. You haven't stated which OS this is for, but in Windows:

[image: Advanced Permissions]

These are the advanced permissions you have available

Comment: Win 7.
If take away the permission to Delete, that means can't modify the content of the file anymore, right?

Comment: I've just tested this to make sure (full control WITHOUT delete). It makes the file unable to be deleted OR renamed, but the contents can still be modified. I believe that's exactly what you wanted?

Comment: @PJMahoney - As stated, full control without delete. I was testing exactly what the delete permission gave. Obviously they will pick and choose the appropriate permissions, I was pointing out I was isolating that particular one.